# What does it mean for avcodec_find_decoder() to return 0?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, codec

This part of my code

```
m_pAVCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
```

is returning 0, which means it failed to find the codec.

What does it mean for ffmpeg to not find a codec? Is it something related with my system? I need somehow to install the h264 codec?

I'm using Ubuntu

**UPDATE:**

By doing
    avcodec_register_all();

before, it works. It's kinda strange because `av_register_all()` was deprecated long ago and won't even compile.

What more needs to be registered?